# How to return value of a nested function

Tags: javascript, openbravo

How can i get a return object from the following function of javascript -

```
function find(model, whereClause, success, error, args) {
    var tableName = model.prototype.tableName,
        propertyMap = model.prototype.propertyMap,
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName,
        params = null,
        appendWhere = true,
        firstParam = true,
        k, v;

    if (db) {
      // websql
      if (whereClause && whereClause._whereClause) {
        whereClause.sql = ' ' + whereClause._whereClause;
      } else {
        whereClause = getWhereClause(whereClause, propertyMap);
      }
      sql = sql + whereClause.sql;
      params = whereClause.params;

      if (model.prototype.propertyMap._idx) {
        sql = sql + ' ORDER BY _idx ';
      }

      if (model.prototype.dataLimit) {
        sql = sql + ' LIMIT ' + model.prototype.dataLimit;
      }

      db.readTransaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sql, params, function (tr, result) {
          var i, collectionType = OB.Collection[model.prototype.modelName + 'List'] || Backbone.Collection,
              collection = new collectionType(),
              len = result.rows.length;
          if (len === 0) {
            success(collection, args);
          } else {
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              collection.add(transform(model, result.rows.item(i)));
            }
            if(success){
             success(collection, args);
            } else {
             return collection
            }
          }
        }, error);
      });
    } else {
      // localStorage
      throw 'Not implemented';
    }
  }
```

I want the variable **collection** within the tx.executeSql() of db.readTransaction to be return when i call the function find() like

```
OB.Dal.find(OB.Model.OutletSection, null, null, null, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call function find like this:

```
OB.Dal.find(OB.Model.OutletSection, null, function(collection, args){

    alert('Collection variable: '+collection);

}, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, actually i am trying to get the result, something like var result = OB.Dal.find(OB.Model.OutletSection, null, null, null, null);

Comment: According the way 'find' function is implemented, you can't. Your return is inside function (tr, result)... which is inside function (tx). You can't catch returned value that way. Those methods are built in order to use in an asynchronous way. You have to write your code replacing my 'alert': var result = collection; .... ;-)